# *ngIf condition is not getting evaluated

Tags: html, angular

HTML code below has a date input field and unordered list of bootstrap class list-group. Based on the template variable for date input html field, i need to load the unordered list. However, the ul is always getting rendered/displayed. what am i missing in the code below?

```
<div style="float:left;">
                <input
                  #queryInvoiceDate
                  (change)="filterInvoiceSingleDate(queryInvoiceDate.valueAsDate)"
                  type="date"
                  class="form-control"
                  style="width:100%"
                  placeholder="Enter date:" >
              </div>
              <br><br>
              <!-- <p *ngIf="queryInvoiceDate"><strong>{{filteredTotalRevenue | currency:'USD'}}</strong></p> -->
              <ul *ngIf="queryInvoiceDate" class="list-group">
                  <li class="list-group-item">Service fee deducted: {{filteredServiceAmountTotal | number:'1.1-2' | currency:'USD'}}</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item">Revenue made by Venue: {{filteredVenueRevenueTotal | number:'1.1-2' | currency:'USD'}}</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item">Total Revenue: {{filteredTotalRevenue | number:'1.1-2' | currency:'USD'}}</li>
              </ul>
```

Comment: How are you getting `queryInvoiceDate` value and do you assign some value to it while initializing?

Comment: @NitishkumarSingh I believe the template variable - `queryInvoiceDate` should be loaded with a value after i enter a date. Its working fine if i use `queryInvoiceDate` on a `<p>` element. If you see the code, i have commented the `<p>` block

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I went through the documntation. My bad. I might need to establish a truthy/falsy state on the component.

Answer (score 0):

I would put something in to filterInvoiceSingleDate like dateSelected=true and use it in the ngIf

html:

```
<ul *ngIf="dateSelected" class="list-group">
```

ts:

```
dateSelected=false
filterInvoiceSingleDate(){
this.dateSelected=true
//your code
}
```

Comment: I know this technique works but my question was different. why doesn't the template variable work on a ul element? But it will work on the `<p>` element which i have commented in the code.

Comment: Just for clarification, the ul should or shouldn't render at the beginning. And the <p> gets rendered but the <ul> not ? or what is the question here

Comment: @NikolaiKiefer - template variables do not establish truthy/falsy states unless we set them in the component. I went through the document. So it neither works on `<p>` nor `<ul>`.

Comment: It should work in the same way, so if you put some text value into the <p> instead of the {{}} then it will be displayed straight away
for your question above: because of the string interpolation